# Vuforia build Error when adding bridging Files

Tags: swift, xcode, vuforia, bridging-header

"Build input file cannot be found:: Path/ Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?" when adding Vuforia Bridging

I want add VuforiaSDK to an iOS project it works smooth until want to add bridging file Error appear like this (Build input file cannot be found: Path/ Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?)

I made some steps :

1- add bridging file to project build setting
2- check more and more about correct path when I add bridging file
3- I uses Xcode Version 14.2
4- clear DerivedData

want to solve this issues